# RangeError: locale must contain localize property when using Angular material date picker with date fns

Tags: angular, angular-material, date-fns, angular-daterangepicker

I have the following configuration on the app-module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DateFnsAdapter, MatDateFnsModule } from '@angular/material-date-fns-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MatDateFormats, MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";


let matLocale = "en-GB"
let dateInput = "DD/MM/YYYY";

export const MY_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: dateInput,
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: dateInput,
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY'
  },
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      CommonModule,
      MatDateFnsModule,
      MatDatepickerModule
    ],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
        useValue: matLocale
      },
      { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS },
      {
        provide: DateAdapter,
        useClass: DateFnsAdapter,
        // deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] // this can be optional since I already provide a value, but I put it for example purposes
      }
    ],
    bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
    ]
)}

export class AppModule { }
```

when I use the component on `app.component.html` I get the error `ERROR RangeError: locale must contain localize property`.

I tried the component with just the `MatNativeDateModule` and removed these lines

```
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: DateFnsAdapter,
      // deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    }
```

and **it works**, since now it's using the `MatNativeDateModule`.

Things that I have tried:

- Added the `MatNativeDateModule` along with the `MatDateFnsModule`.
- Used the `deps` option for the injection of `MAT_DATE_LOCALE`

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After looking through the code from the date-fns adapter, it is required to specify `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` to the selected date-fns locale.

```js
// app.module.ts

import { es } from 'date-fns/locale';

providers: [
    {
        provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
        useValue: es,
    },
],
```

Note: The locale on `useValue` is not a string.

Comment: How can we set the locale from a known string at runtime?, e.g. 'en-AU' ?

Comment: Open issue - https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2082.  You might want to go there and chime in.

Comment: [moments later - but not soon enough that SO would allow an edit]  I found [this solution](https://robertmarshall.dev/blog/dynamically-import-datefns-locale-mui-datepicker-localization/) - it appears to be specific to MUI and React, but might serve as a template for an Angular version.  Who knows?  More poking around might turn up an existing Angular solution.  But it's a point of curiosity for me right now, not a problem I'm actively trying to solve.

Comment: getting closer (after I promised myself I wouldn't dig into this now): https://indepth.dev/posts/1038/dynamic-import-of-locales-in-angular
(this is closer, but not a precise match for the date-fns scenario)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by setting locale in the constructor. Not really clean, but fixes the issue.

```js
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { enUS } from 'date-fns/locale';

export class DatepickerComponent {
  constructor(private _adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {
    this._adapter.setLocale(enUS);
  }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer was working for the application but not with storybook. Your answer fixed it for that case so thank you :)